# Properly sending HTTP response over sockets

Tags: c++, sockets

I have a sockets app, and want to allow browsers to send/receive data. Unfortunately, for some odd reason, this code just will not work for Chrome, nor curl. What is strange though, is it seems to work almost perfectly fine with Internet Explorer Edge, and even some REST playgrounds available on the internet.

What could be the cause of this? I want to assume it's something to do with headers, but, I sent headers exactly matching another domain, and still, it stalls.

What seems to happen is Chrome loads the data, but, stalls, and an official response is never received -- or maybe it just never finished? I can see all text on the page, however, google is still loading, and the "Server Response" reports that it received nothing. In addition to that, I think it's sending the same response to a client twice.

Here is my code:

```
// sockserver.cpp : Defines the entry point for the console application.
//

#define WIN32_LEAN_AND_MEAN
#include <winsock2.h>
#include <process.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <map>
#pragma comment(lib,"ws2_32.lib" )

unsigned int __stdcall  ServClient(void *data);

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{

    WSADATA wsaData;
    int iResult;
    sockaddr_in addr;
    SOCKET sock, client;

    addr.sin_family = AF_INET;
    addr.sin_port = htons(5900);
    addr.sin_addr.S_un.S_addr = inet_addr("192.168.0.22");

    iResult = WSAStartup(MAKEWORD(2, 2), &wsaData);//2.2 

    if (iResult)
    {
        printf("WSA startup failed");
        return 0;
    }


    sock = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, IPPROTO_TCP);

    if (sock == INVALID_SOCKET)
    {
        printf("Invalid socket");
        return 0;
    }

    iResult = bind(sock, (sockaddr*)&addr, sizeof(sockaddr_in));

    if (iResult)
    {

        printf("bind failed %u", GetLastError());

        return 0;
    }

    iResult = listen(sock, SOMAXCONN);

    if (iResult)
    {

        printf("iResult failed %u", GetLastError());

        return 0;
    }

    while (client = accept(sock, 0, 0))
    {
        if (client == INVALID_SOCKET)
        {
            printf("invalid client socket", GetLastError());
            continue;
        }
        _beginthreadex(0, 0, ServClient, (void*)&client, 0, 0);

    }


    return 0;
}

std::map<int, SOCKET> sockList;
unsigned int __stdcall ServClient(void *data)
{
    SOCKET* client = (SOCKET*)data;
    SOCKET Client = *client;
    printf("Client connected\n");

    int xx = 0;

    char chunk[200];
    while (recv(Client, chunk, 200, 0))
    {

        char buf[] = "HTTP/1.1 200 OK\nContent-Type: text/html\nAccept: */*;Date:Sun, 21 Feb 2016 18:26:33 GMT\nServer: ubersnip\nContent-Length:18076\nAccept-Encoding:gzip, deflate, sdch\nAccept-Language:en-US,en;q=0.8\nCache-Control:max-age=0\nConnection:keep-alive\nHost:localhost:2222\nSet-Cookie:acct=t=t%2flE8KL9jDBOed05o1eMDiINlDfMvLxp&s=CUBOpXFMXmBt4u3pf%2fx5efr5WWkyGT3U; domain=.stackoverflow.com; expires=Sun, 21-Aug-2016 18:26:33 GMT; path=/; HttpOnly\n\n<html><body>Hello World</body></html>";

        //sockList[sockList.size()] = Client;
        send(Client, buf, strlen(buf), 0);
        /*if (xx >= 1) {
            closesocket(Client);
            return 1;
        }
        else {
            xx++;
        }*/
        printf("%s \t %d\n", chunk, GetCurrentThreadId());
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I think that need to remove tag google-chrome from question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are setting a huge Content-length of 18076 but your content is much much smaller. Thus the browser will wait for more content. But instead of providing more content you simply wait for the browser to send another request and thus both client and server are waiting for each other.

Apart from that lots of headers you send make no sense: Accept, Accept-Encoding, Accept-Language and Host are all headers which are relevant for the request and make no sense in the response. And the proper line ending with HTTP is `\r\n` and not `\n` although browsers usually don't care about this detail.

Comment: Ah that makes tones of sense now! :D So how do I determine the content-length? Is it by number of characters, and also, should that include Headers?

Comment: @user2292759: The content-length is the length of the body only, in octets (bytes) and not in (maybe multi-byte) characters.

Comment: Thanks! Works perfectly now! Something told me it was the headers. Thanks a bunch! :D

Answer (score 1):

> What seems to happen is Chrome loads the data, but, **stalls**

As you mentioned it 'stalls', looking at your code, you are calling 'recv', which is a blocking call. If there is no data available, recv will block.

Could this be where you are stalling? There are APIs available to check if there is data available first, to allow you to avoid blocking conditions. Just mentioning this incase it helps.

If you make it to the 'send()', I doubt you'd stall, but that too could be possible.

Comment: Thanks for that! Loads much faster now.... Not really sure why I was using while :) Appreciated!

PS:
I THINK that also fixed the double sending ;)

Comment: I have a question in regards to this though, and I guess this is why I used while.

If the same client resends data, how can I decipher which client it is that has sent the data.... With the while, the thread never closed, so, I was able to get data and distinguish between clients. Suggestions?